# Where to find tooltip text for Remember me? Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Im trying to change the following:

Check "Remember Me" to access your shopping cart on this computer even if you are not signed in.

It's part of the tooltip for "Remember me (Whats this?)" on register and login.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this location:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml
```

or

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml
```

If you use some custom theme then you have this file or you can copy it to your template destination.

```
/app/design/frontend/[change this to namespace of template]/[change this to name of template]/template/persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml
```

Comment: Sorry should have put in the title Magento 2

Comment: No problem :). Check your answear to right one for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! (Feeling slightly stupid ;)

```
module-persistent/view/frontend/templates/remember_me.phtml
```

But thanks @Patryk for pointing me in the rough direction